# Parallel Workers Not Being Used With BRIN Index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, database-performance

We're currently running a query that performs a pretty simple join and group by for a row count and at the end a union all.

```
(select
table_p."name",
table_p.id,
count(table.id),
sum(table.views)
    from table
        inner join table_p on table_p.id = table.pageid
        where table.date BETWEEN '2020-03-01' AND '2020-03-31'
            group by table_p.id
            order by table_p.id)
union all
(select
table_p."name",
table_p.id,
count(table.id),
sum(table.views)
    from table
        inner join table_p on table_p.id = table.pageid
        where table.date BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-29'
            group by table_p.id
            order by table_p.id)
union all ....
```

We've decided to use a BRIN index due to the count of our table being 360 million records. We do have the option to go with B-Tree if needed.

Now for some reason, we're seeing in the explain analyze that the BRIN Index has "parallel aware" set to false with two workers being listed in the plan outputted? Also we're seeing a linear performance when breaking up the amount that we're querying, i.e. one month in 5 seconds, four months in 20 seconds. I'd assume this means that we're querying asynchronously rather than parallel.

Does anyone have any ideas on what we could potentially be missing in order to get parallel queries going where possible? Does BRIN not work with Parallel Workers?

Edit: Here is the BRIN index on "table":

```
CREATE INDEX table_brin_idx
    ON table USING brin
    (date, teamid, id, pageid, devicetypeid, makeid, modelid)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

My postgres version is PostgreSQL 11.6, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit

[Here's a link to the explain analyze that's too big to post here.](https://www.codepile.net/raw/W0ANlwJ1.json)

Comment: Which table has the BRIN index, and on what columns? What version of PG? Include the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output.

Comment: @AdamKG I've added what you requested at the bottom of my post.

Comment: JSON may be nice for machines to read, but as EXPLAIN output is mostly illegible to humans, such as me.  Please show the text format.  But I can tell that your plan is in fact using parallel workers, notice several occurrences of `"Workers Launched": 2,`

Comment: The query is using 2 workers for each Gather Merge node within each SELECT, but is using a non-parallel Append node at the top-level to combine the UNION ALLs, and so each month is queried sequentially, taking ~4.5s per month. I'm not sure why it's not using a ParallelAppend. See if the EXPLAIN changes with `set effictive_io_concurrency = 10` (default is 1), `set max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 8` (default 2), or both. Note that if you're IO-bound, the planner is probably correct to use a regular Append, and you won't actually get a faster result from a ParallelAppend query plan.

Comment: @AdamKG upping the max gatherers did get postgres to use 4 workers instead of 2. Sped things up ever so slightly when querying for all 12 months. We're not IO bound when checking our usage on Azure. Not even being throttled by CPU usage either.

Comment: I'm curious what would happen if you made the UNION ALL parts simpler and moved the joins to the result of that. Something like `SELECT <grouping columns>, count(subq.id), sum(subq.views) from (select * from table where <first month WHERE> union all select * from table where <2nd month WHERE> ...) subq JOIN table_p on <join_cond> group by <grouping conds>`. I'm basing this on there being a HashAggregate node for each month, which I think counts as a node with an InitPlan, which would disable ParallelAppend for that plan. Other than that, I'm out of ideas, this is a bit out of my depth.

Comment: Reference for initplans causing parallelappend to be disabled from [this commit](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/0927d2f46ddd4cf7d6bf2cc84b3be923e0aedc52#diff-484f04307710b5e7b30cc2e6a06b7420R2206-R2210).

Answer (score 1):

Information from PostgreSQL documentation: Currently, parallel index scans are supported only for **btree** indexes. 
Source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/parallel-plans.html#PARALLEL-SCANS